# After login redirect to different page according to user role

Tags: php, redirect, mysqli

I would like to modify my code to redirect to different pages after login depending on user roles, I have only been able to make one universal redirect regardless of the role. I need help on how to implement that.

Here is my db table of users:

```
userID  fullname    email               role    password
1       Tester one  test@gmail.com      N       ALSJALDDJ6464!JJLSK
2       Tester two  tester@gmail.com    C       @ALSJAL5656DDJJJLSK
```

My PHP login Code is here:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// establishing the MySQLi connection

// Create connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "timewise";

$conn = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// checking the user
if(isset($_POST['btnLogin'])){
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['uemail']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['upass']);

//$pass = crypt($pass);


$sel_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND pass='$pass'";

$run_user = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_user);
if (!$sel_user) {
die(mysqli_error($conn));
}

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

if($check_user>0){
$user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_user);

if ($user_data["role"] == 'C') {
    //redirect somehwere
    print '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "index.html"</script>';
} else {
    //redirect somehwere else
    print '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "form-wizard.html"</script>';
}
} else {
    // more code here
    echo '<center><span style="color:#801b1b; border:1px solid #e5a3a3; background:#ffcfcf; padding:5px;">Email or password is not correct, please try again!</span></center>';
}

}

?>
```

I need help on redirecting logged in users to different pages depending on the role i.e. either

> "N" for normal user OR "C" for company user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's start:

```
$sel_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND pass='$pass'";
$run_user = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_user);

// this will never happens as $sel_user is a string and it's not empty
// I suppose you need to check `$run_user`
if (!$sel_user) {
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
} 

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
if($check_user>0){
    // here you need $run_user data
    // use fetch_ methods, for example `fetch_assoc()`
    $user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_user);
    // print_r($user_data) to check keys
    if ($user_data["role"] == 'C') {
        //redirect somehwere
    } else {
        //redirect somehwere else
    }
} else {
    // more code here
}
```

Comment: I have tried it that way but only one redirect is working

Comment: What is exactly the code, you've tried? Use a pastebin or update a question.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `header('location: /file')` function to immediately redirect to a different page according to user position in some `if/else` or have the link as a variable and it would be `header("location: " . $file)`. I hope that this is helpful!