# Redirect to different pages on login- php

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to redirect an admin to a page and other users to a different page.
Able to do in procedure but not in oop.
An admin might add new users and display them n has a whole lot of jobs to do whereas a user can see only his/her page.

```
<?php
require_once('userClass.php'); 
$userObj = new USER(); 
session_start();
$type = $_GET['type'];


if(empty($type) || !isset($type)) {

  echo 'Request type is not set';

} else if($type == 'signup') {

   $data =  USER::addNewUser($_REQUEST);
   $_SESSION = $data;
   if($data['status'] == 'error') {
     header("location:register.php");
   } else {
     header("location:index.php");
   }
} else if($type == 'login') {
   $username = addslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
   $password = addslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
   $_SESSION =  USER::login($username, $password);
   if($_SESSION['status'] == 'error') {
     header("location:index.php");
   } 
   else {

     header("location:profile.php");

   }
   /*if($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin@admin.com') {
     header("location:admin.php");
   } 
   else {

     header("location:profile.php");

   }*/


} else if($type == 'logout') {
 unset($_SESSION);
 session_destroy();
 header("location:index.php");
}


?>
```

Looking for a solution....Please help.
*Look at the comented section in code.

Comment: first check data saved in `$_SESSION['username']`, do `echo $_SESSION['username']`

Comment: What is not working? What's the problem with the code you commented out?

Comment: Thank you guys for your valuable coments....I got the answer.I had to do $_SESSION['username']=$username;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After login redirect to different page according to user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35729565/after-login-redirect-to-different-page-according-to-user-role)

Answer (score 1):

One of the easy way to do so is to define the role.

For example

```
if($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin@admin.com' && $_POST['role'] = 'admin'){
       header("location:admin.php");
 } 
 else {

 header("location:profile.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code, hope this helps.

```
if($_SESSION['status'] == 'error') {
     header("Location: index.php");
   } 
   else {

    if($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin@admin.com') {
     header("Location: admin.php");
   } 
   else {

     header("Location: profile.php");

   }

}
```